# Why do some Support Barbarian builds use the Gem of Ease if the Barbarian does not kill anything?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

The [Gem of Ease](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/gem-of-ease) grants experience based on monster kills, and yet I saw some people in Season Ten using this gem in the weapon of a zero DPS support barbarian (which does not kill any monsters).

What sense does it make to use the Gem of Ease in a support barbarian, if the barbarian does not kill anything?

I know that if the wearer of the gem kills a monster, every party member gets the experience bonus of the gem (I tried this already several times while levelling additional characters to level 70 in a party).

So the only reason I can imagine people equip this gem, is that it also triggers on party member kills. Does this work? Will the whole party get an experience bonus from the gem if another party member kills a monster?

In other words, does this gem work in the same way as the [Oculus ring](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/oculus-ring)?

Comment: Did you see a party in action? Or just the best barbarian on the rank with that gem? Because that rank is perma-changing so, maybe he change their barbarian and just left that pj with the weapon and the ease. I saw so many people doing this to not get copied by another people and get reached on the rank.

Comment: Gem of Ease has lvl 25 effect that reduces a weapon lvl requirement to 0, Maybe barb was low level, and weapon has some beneficial legendary affix?

Comment: @Dpeif No I am talking about 80+.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All experience boosts are divided among all party members.  So in a 4-person party:

- 1 person has +4% exp = each person gets +1%.
- 1 person has a gem of ease with +2400 exp on kill = each person gets +600 exp on kill.

I can't find a reference, but I distinctly remember the patch where they made the change.  Before that people would play support builds with tons of +exp % and level faster than people doing the actual damage, so they modified it so the benefits go to everyone in the party to make zero-dps builds less attractive.

Edit:
Thanks to Orc JMR for the source - [patch 2.3](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/patch-notes/2-3-0):

> Experience gained, including all sources of Bonus Experience, is now averaged across all players in a party that are eligible to receive experience

Comment: This would mean, the barb gets no exp and the other three get 600 exp per kill.

Comment: @ceving No, in a party it's all shared.  So 2400/4 = 600 to each.  You don't have to do damage to get a share of the kill.  In rifts you just need to be on the same rift level.

Answer (score 1):

In a DPS build, there is only one gem that really ever gets used: Emeralds. Emeralds increase the critical damage percentage, so that's why it's used.

In a supporting role, there is no need for the emerald, so a gem of ease is used instead. The gem of ease is NOT granted to the entire party, but only to the user wearing it. You still get EXP for being in the same dungeon as the person who killed an enemy, so anything that increases exp is helpful even if you're not killing anything.

At a certain point in the season and paragon level, increasing any other stat is useless compared to the increase you get in paragon level stats. So the only thing that really matters at that point is exp and paragon level, so the gem of ease is used.

Comment: 1.) The natural gem for a weapon of a support char is a amethyst. 2.) The exp is granted to the party, I have verified it as I have written in the question. Without the gem **all** members doing a T1 rift with a level 1 char are lower than level 10 after finishing the guardian and with the gem **all** members are at a level greater than 40. This means **all** benefit from the gem, although just one wears it. 3.) Nothing in the answer explains why the gem should give exp without killing an enemy.

Comment: 1.) Like I said, once you get to a certain point, the other gems don't grant you enough stats to not get 1 shot and die, so it's more beneficial to use a gem of ease. 2.) I haven't played in a couple of seasons, but this is not the way exp bonuses worked when I played. 3.) The experience mechanics will answer why this gem gives you additional experience without killing the enemy https://www.diablowiki.net/Experience